# Can someone please explain this error I'm getting in my script

Tags: bash, shell-script, git, dot-files, github

I'm trying to create a script which I can set as a cron job which adds all my dotfiles to a folder I've set up as a github repo then push them every evening. My script is the following.

```
cp ~/.!(|.|ssh|bash_logout|bash_history) ~/dotfiles

git add .

git commit -m "Test commit"

git push origin master
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
./update_dotfiles.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./update_dotfiles.sh: line 3: `cp ~/.!(|.|ssh|bash_logout|bash_history) ~/dotfiles'
```

The command works perfectly when I run it it just errors when i'm running is as part of a shell script.The script is running bash,

Comment: Which shell are you executing it with when running manually and when invoking from a script?

Comment: It's running in bash, sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Please manually expand the `~`, it may not work in all scripts

Comment: Put `shopt extglob` on the line before the `cp` command and post what it prints out.

Comment: In an interactive bash shell, the `extglob` option is enabled by default (I think), but for a non-interactive script, you have to explicitly turn it on.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the bash shell in the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for this to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

When bash runs a script without a shebang or with `#!/bin/sh` it runs in [POSIX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html) which has some limitations.

You also need to enable the `extglob` shell option in `bash` to make it understand the `!(...)` globbing pattern:

```
shopt -s extglob
```